# Scala MultipartEntityBuilder is not creating the boundary correctly for a Spring Rest point

Tags: spring, scala, post, httpclient, multipartform-data

I have a request body that consists of more than one body part and below is how I am handling it in scala using a multipartentitybuilder library in scala.

> `val data = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
>         .setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE)
>         .addPart("actual Header", new StringBody(actualHeader,ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON))
>         .addBinaryBody("payload", requestBody)
>         .build()`

for context, the binary body is a Byte[] of an avro event that needs to be sent to this post request.

On Attempting to send this entity to a spring rest endpoint via httpPost, I am getting the following exception in response.

> org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Failed to parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found

**What I have tried:**

- I tried to manually add a boundary with .setBoundary() but that did not help.
- There was another way to go in the other solutions available online. I could get rid of the headers that say ContentType.Application-JSON, however removing that is going to fail at the API level, since they have checks for it, so that wouldn't work either.
- I tried adding the binary body as a part to make it consistent which made the code look like this

> `val data = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
>         .setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE)
>         .addPart("Event Header", new StringBody(eventHeader,ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON))
>         .addPart("payload",new ByteArrayBody(requestBody, ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY, null.asInstanceOf[String]))
>         .build()`

- Tried to have the multipartEntityBuilder create the textbody (for JSON part)
  and bytearray for payload part and got rid of content Type, using the following code

> `val data = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
>         .setBoundary(boundary)
>         .addTextBody("Event Header",eventHeader,ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON)     .addBinaryBody("Payload",requestBody,ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY,null.asInstanceOf[String])
>         .build()`

this got me further as in it autodetected the ContentType as `multipart/form-data` but when I setEntity to post, it did not transfer that information over to the POST and that still didn't correctly assign the boundary as part of the content type in the header

- Also tried to add header from a file making sure the two bodies were consistent in nature with the following code

> `val file = new File("eventHeader.json")
>   val data = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
>         .setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE)
>         .addBinaryBody("Event Header",file,ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON,"eventHeader.json")
>         .addBinaryBody("Avro Payload",requestBody)
>         .build()`

No luck

For more context and info, below are the other attributes to the POST request

```
val post = new HttpPost(url);
val client: CloseableHttpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
post.setConfig(requestConfig)
post.setHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data")
post.setEntity(data)

val response: HttpResponse = client.execute(post)
```

Another piece of information, when I debug the entity in IntelliJ it shows me a boundary that is created but I don't see it anywhere physically on the content.(not sure how helpful this information is)

Now, the exception is referencing to springframework and I have a nagging suspicion that scala is not playing well with that. However, we have successfully implemented gatling test scenarios in scala so it is not completely impossible to pull that off.

Hence, I now surrender to the community's expertise on how to go about solving this without being too invasive because this is going to be part of a spark service so let's not ignore the data distribution aspect of it all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it to work with a simple addition of boundary from the content type of the data originally generated.

Below is how I changed my code for the request to go through,

> `val file = new File("testHeader.json")`
>
> ```
>    val data = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
>   .setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE)
>   .addBinaryBody("Event Header",file,ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON,"testHeader.json")
>   .addBinaryBody("Avro Payload",requestBody)
>   .build()
> ```

```
val client: CloseableHttpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

val APIUrl = url

val post = new HttpPost(APIUrl);
post.setConfig(requestConfig)
post.setHeader(data.getContentType)
post.setEntity(data)
```

Simple solution but kind of a work around, for some reason (that I am not aware of) it didn't auto detect the type when I didn't set the content type at all. Hopefully this helps another poor dud like me sometime in the future.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution. In my case (Java + Apache Camel) I had to set the boundary more explicitly, by using both `builder.setBoundary("BLA-BLA")` and `setHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=BLA-BLA")`.